# Power Automate Flow doesn't fire when submitting from PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps-forms

I have a PowerApps app that uses a SharePoint list as a data source. There is a Flow associated with that SharePoint list that is set to trigger when an item is added or updated. When I submit an item to the list from PowerApps, the item is created, but the Flow does not fire. If I create or edit the item directly in SharePoint, the Flow triggers and runs as expected. Is this a known bug, or do I have to design the flow differently?

Comment: Here is a link showing some [troubleshooting tips](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/triggers-troubleshoot)

Comment: Do you have any trigger conditions configured for the flow? If so, perhaps creating the list item in PowerApps is not meeting those trigger conditions.

Comment: I found the issue- it was the trigger condition- I had a condition set to prevent the flow from re-triggering itself by editing the item. That trigger was blocking the flow from running at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, thanks to Matiur's link to the troubleshooting tips. I had a trigger condition set to prevent the flow from running if the triggering entity was the service account we have that we used to build the flow. That prevented it from firing at all when it was triggered from PowerApps.